# Check object and it's property for null with discard "_" in one expression C#

Tags: c#

I like using discards while checking object for null and if it's null throw exception.
like this:

```
using System;

public class C
{
    public class Mind
    {
        
    }
    
    public class Human
    {
        public Mind Mind { get; set; }
    }
    
    public void M(Human animal)
    {
        _ = animal ?? throw new Exception("");
        _ = animal.Mind ?? throw new Exception("");
    }
}
```

decompiled version of this code (method M) would be

```
public void M(Human animal)
{
    if (animal == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("");
    }
    if (animal.Mind == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("");
    }
}
```

Which way would be nice, beautiful and optimal to check both "aminal" and "animal.Mind" at the same time in one expression?
I have two variants.

```
_ = ((object)animal ?? throw new Exception("")) ?? animal.Mind ?? throw new Exception("");
//Decompiled without { & }
if (animal == null)
   throw new Exception("");
if (animal == null && animal.Mind == null)
   throw new Exception("");
        
_ = ((object)animal ?? animal.Mind) switch { null => throw new Exception(""), _ => animal };
//Decompiled without { & }
object obj = ((object)animal) ?? ((object)animal.Mind);
if (obj == null)
   throw new Exception("");
```

Comment: That discards and the ternary operator exist doesn't suddenly make `if` obsolete. It's subjective, but nothing of what you demonstrate is "nice" compared to writing code everyone on the planet can understand, and you can't even claim a line tax -- `if (animal == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(animal));`. VS can even generate this automatically.

Comment: What's more, if you feel the need for discards, then apparently you're not even using the argument, which just raises further questions. A standard pattern would be something like `this.animal = animal ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(...)`. If all you need is the `animal`s `Mind` property, why not just pass `Mind` directly and save a check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a one-liner using the [Elvis operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
_ = animal?.Mind ?? throw new Exception("");
```

Or without using discards:

```
if (animal?.Mind == null) throw new Exception("");
```